# Dollar sign and digits (Joomla + Jumi)

Tags: php, joomla, jumi

I have db with this string content:

```
[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]
```

Need to echo it as it is.

When try to echo

```
echo "[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]";
```

got this:

```
[] [$ 3] [.2]
```

Tried urlencode, htmlspecialchars, but didn't succeed.

How do I echo and get this?

```
[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]
```

EDIT:

single quotes is not giving wanted result.

```
echo '[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]';

[] [$ 3] [.2]
```

My php version is 5.2.14 and I am using Joomla.

EDIT2:

I figured out, the reason it's not working with single quotes is because of Joomla + Jumi. If I use pure php - it works ok.

Comment: Are you sure you are using php? Can you show us how do you test your code? Are you using the command line like `php file.php` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use single quotes if you don't want the variable values to be interpolated.

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

```
echo '[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]';
```

The quotes shouldn't matter for this *particular* case as PHP variables can't start with numbers.

For example:

```
echo '[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]'; // single-quoted
```

will have the same effect as:

```
echo "[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]"; // double-quoted
```

And both should output:

```
[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]
```

But, for valid variables, the above rules apply.

Example:

```
$var = 'foo';
$string = 'this is a string with $var';
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
this is a string with $var
```

[**Demo!**](http://3v4l.org/WCiUT)

Comment: escape the $ with backslashes. `echo "[\$3] [\$ 3] [\$3.2]";

Comment: @ihtus: Yes, I have. See the demo.

Comment: @XaxD: That's another way to do it, but it makes code look ugly, and can get tedious of there are a lot of `$`s to escape :)

Comment: true, that's why i put out str_replace() to automate the process, but he says single quotes didn't fix the issue for him.

Comment: Amal Murali: this is really weird, my php 5.2.14 is outputting [] [$ 3] [.2] even with single quotes..

Comment: @ihtus: if you check the [**demo here**](http://3v4l.org/etERo), you can see that it's working fine on all versions of PHP from 4.3.1 - 5.5.3.

Comment: ok, plain php - works as should... the reason it is not working is because I am using Joomla. Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

Within double quotes, PHP is interpreting anything that starts with a `$` as a variable, and trying to output the contents of `$3`.

When you don't want that behavior, simply use single quotes:

```
echo '[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]';
```

Comment: What's odd is that `$3` is not a valid variable name, and on my local install, PHP knows this.

Answer (score 1):

A single-quoted string does not have variables within it interpreted. A double-quoted string does.

Also, a double-quoted string can contain apostrophes without backslashes, while a single-quoted string can contain unescaped quotation marks.

The single-quoted strings are faster at runtime because they do not need to be parsed.

Try this one

```
 echo '[$3] [$ 3] [$3.2]';
```

details here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php